# Need appearing text when scrolling carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm using 'Owl Carousel' to scroll content on my page. Below the carousel I have a special block for text. When i'm scrolling, I need this text to append there, but i'm not strong enough in jq to make that happen.
 A text have to append dependently of an element that will be on a center of carousel.

For example: When i scroll and element number 1 is on center, i need that will append text: "Hello, this is first element". 
 And when i scroll next, the first text have to disappear and a text of second carousel element have to appear instead.

Have anybody idea how to make it?

```js
// I'm using a plugin Owl Carousel 2.2.1

$('.projects-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:30,
    nav:true,
    center:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        1600:{
            items:2,
            stagePadding:75
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel projects-carousel">
    <div class="projects-Wrapper">
        <div class="projects-img-wrapper">
            <a class="popup-youtube" href="#"><img src="img/projects/1.png" alt="Jey The Dog"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects-Wrapper">
        <div class="projects-img-wrapper">
        <a class="popup-youtube" href="#"><img src="img/projects/2.png" alt="Jey The Cat"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="text-block">
    <!--Here have to append a text, but i also dont know on which way to connect between element in carousel and its text... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my own question, maybe somebody will need it in the future. That's how i solved it:

```js
('.projects-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:30,
    nav:true,
    center:true,
    mouseDrag:false,
    touchDrag:false,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],
    items: 3
  });
  
    
//By default, places content of central carousel's element into the page.
$('.projects-h3 h3').html($('.center .project-content h3').html());
  $('.projects-text p').html($('.center .project-content p').html());

/* Finds central element in .PROJECTS carousel(by '.center' class which is part of owl carousel plugin) every time when 
navigation button used and replaces the text content with a needed text.
*/
$(".projects-carousel .owl-nav").click(function(){
  $('.projects-h3 h3').html($('.center .project-content h3').html());
  $('.projects-text p').html($('.center .project-content p').html());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the text inside the carousel:

```
<div class="owl-carousel projects-carousel">
    <div class="projects-Wrapper">
        <div class="projects-img-wrapper">
            <a class="popup-youtube" href="#"><img src="img/projects/1.png" alt="Jey The Dog"></a>
        </div>
        <p>Text you'd like here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="projects-Wrapper">
        <div class="projects-img-wrapper">
        <a class="popup-youtube" href="#"><img src="img/projects/2.png" alt="Jey The Cat"></a>
        </div>
        <p>Text you'd like here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then position using CSS:

```
.projects-Wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.projects-Wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Sliding with carousel is not looks as it have to.. Need the text to append in DOM.